# flutter build apk --release - throwing "Your project requires a higher compileSdkVersion" error

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to build a release APK and I get these errors:

```
Warning: The plugin firebase_core requires Android SDK version 31.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin firebase_crashlytics requires Android SDK version 31.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin flutter_email_sender requires Android SDK version 31.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle requires Android SDK version 31.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin image_picker_android requires Android SDK version 31.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin local_auth requires Android SDK version 31.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin path_provider_android requires Android SDK version 31.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin shared_preferences_android requires Android SDK version 31.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin sqflite requires Android SDK version 31.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to E:\Work\projects/mobileapp\android\app\build.gradle:
android {
  compileSdkVersion 31
  ...
}



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseAarMetadata'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
        Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
        AAR metadata file: D:\Users\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2c5bbadbc54ffe3d592218b7d11658e5\jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
        Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
        AAR metadata file: D:\Users\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1cb17a1ca0633fa43b0d1d11a0d2f3f7\jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
        Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1.
        AAR metadata file: D:\Users\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\ecc0883e5e412cbeee4817b0064467cb\appcompat-1.4.1\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
        Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1.
        AAR metadata file: D:\Users\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b159961f157d61d438c03cde4259be22\jetified-appcompat-resources-1.4.1\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
        Dependency: androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views-helper:1.0.0.
        AAR metadata file: D:\Users\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\bd75d8ee46f4b15348d2c4f1e0f934aa\jetified-emoji2-views-helper-1.0.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
        Dependency: androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.0.0.
        AAR metadata file: D:\Users\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d7d9e2aa3a4919a6b018407f5a53fc08\jetified-emoji2-1.0.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
        Dependency: androidx.core:core:1.8.0.
        AAR metadata file: D:\Users\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\cef2c25e040dac8d9865e80f67f4812f\core-1.8.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
        Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.4.0.
        AAR metadata file: D:\Users\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\fce3906ee80d310aa4d4587e6e9833a2\jetified-lifecycle-process-2.4.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
        Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.4.0.
        AAR metadata file: D:\Users\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3ca1e4c4b4500ce99856badada74ac1e\lifecycle-runtime-2.4.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           15,9s

┌─ Flutter Fix ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a higher compileSdkVersion.                                                             │
│ Fix this issue by bumping the compileSdkVersion in E:\projects\mobileapp\android\app\build.gradle: │
│ android {                                                                                                         │
│   compileSdkVersion 31                                                                                            │
│ }                                                                                                                 │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Thing is I set the compileSdkVersion even higher, to 33:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
...
}
```

I did invalidate & cache Android Studio.

What to do to fix it?

(I did try to set back to 31 still the same error thrown)

So yeah... Sdk version 31 or 33, it is not working. I also downloaded in SDK manager the SDKs from  31 to 33. In SDK tools the Android SDK Build-Tools 33...

Comment: try this -> `compileSdkVersion 31, minSdkVersion 23, targetSdkVersion 29`

Comment: No success using these numbers.

Comment: Can you provide yaml file if problem is still happening

Answer (score 3):

I run into the same issue.
To fix it:

- I deleted the `android` folder in my flutter project,
- created a new flutter project,
- copied the `android` folder from the new flutter project
- then pasted it to my project.

Answer (score 0):

i just replaced my andriod folder of old flutter project with andriod folder from any latest flutter project and run it , successfuly executed.